# Htaccess shows both: short url and long at the same time

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

everyone!
I need help, because, I don't understand how's it can be.

I have easy htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?cat=$1

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

When I open any page, i have to see smth like this:

```
site.com/games
```

but I see:

```
site.com/games?cat=games.
```

What can it be and how can I resolve this? Very sorry, if this question was already resolved here, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap the order of your rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?cat=$1
```

I also tweaked your rules a little, removing unnecessary QSA flag and unused capturing. Also specifying an external redirect for the first one.

Let me know any problems.